# Python applying a list of functions to a list of items including None values

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

If I have a list of data-items where I'd like to convert type

for example:

```
row = (u'2013-13-04 00:00:00',
     u'P1',
     u'BRT64510',
     u'CHUCKLES MOTOR COMPANY',
     u'123',
     None,
     u'2345',
     u'100000',
     u'150000000',
     None,
     u'100000',
     None,
     u'123345',
     u'1234567',
     u'122445',
     None)
```

and a list of conversion formulae for example:

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime
st = lambda x: dt.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
f = lambda x: float(x)
s = lambda x: str(x)

conversion = [st, s, s, s, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f]
```

I'm trying to apply something along the lines of:

```
result =[func(value) for func,value in zip(conversion,row)]
```

but of course I'm getting errors with the `NULL : None` values.

Is there a quick fix that will allow me to apply a list of functions to a list of items while leaving the nulls as null? This cleanup will be applied to a large list of records so I don't know which values will be null in advance.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change your `f` function, like this

```
f = lambda x: float(x) if isinstance(x, unicode) else x
```

Or this

```
f = lambda x: float(x) if x is not None else x
```

Now, if the input is of type `unicode` (or in the second case if `x` is not `None`), it will call `float` on it.

In your case, you simply can avoid the `lambda` functions, and make

```
conversion = [st, str, str, str, float, ...]
```

and then include the condition in the list comprehension itself, like this

```
[val if value is None else func(val) for func, val in zip(conversion, row)]
```

**Note:** Your date is not in the right format, you may want to change the format, like this

```
dt.strptime(x,'%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')
```

so that it will match

```
'2013-13-04 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Thanks @thefourtheye - Very comprehensive answer and appreciate the heads up on the datetime too.

Comment: @Downvoter, please let me know how I can improve this answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
result = [func(value) if value is not None else None
          for func, value in zip(conversion, row)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be adding `identity` function for `NULL` values.

```
>>> i = lambda x: x
>>> conversion = [st, s, s, s, f, i, f, f, f, i, f, i, f, f, f, i]
>>> result = [func(value) for func, value in zip(conversion, row)]
```

---

By the way, your datetime conversion format is not correct. It should be the following:

```
st = lambda x: dt.strptime(x,'%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the datetime @ozgur

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider `itertools.starmap()` for this function.

Let us assume that you create a function that takes a function and an argument and returns the value of what the function returns,

```
def myApply(f, v): 
    try: return f(v)
    except: return None
```

Then, you could use `starmap` to apply these functions to the values in order:

```
import itertools as itt
result = itt.starmap( myApply, zip( conversion, row ) )
```

The `try`-`except` method will be able to catch all sorts of problems. However, it will *silently* just convert the result to `None`. If you dont want this behavior, you can consider changing the `except` option to something more meaningful ...

Answer (score 1):

```
result =[None if isinstance(value, type(None)) else func(value) for func,value in zip(conversion,row)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a try/except structure with a conversion function:

```
def conv(f, x):
    try:
        return f(x)
        # TypeError catches float(None)
        # add ValueError if you might get float('abc') for example...
    except TypeError: 
        return x

result =[conv(func, value) for func,value in zip(conversion,row)]
```

Then you approach works perfectly (once you correct the `dt.strstrptime(x,'%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')`):

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime
st = lambda x: dt.strptime(x,'%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')
f = lambda x: float(x)
s = lambda x: str(x)

conversion = [st, s, s, s, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f]    

def conv(f, x):
    try:
        return f(x)
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        return x

result =[conv(func, value) for func,value in zip(conversion,row)]    
print result
```

Prints:

```
[datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 13, 0, 0), 'P1', 'BRT64510', 'CHUCKLES MOTOR COMPANY', 123.0, None, 2345.0, 100000.0, 150000000.0, None, 100000.0, None, 123345.0, 1234567.0, 122445.0, None]
```